# Why does multiplying two fractional Doubles and converting the result to a String result in extraneous zeroes?

Tags: swift, type-conversion

```
var d1 = 0.124 * 0.12456 // 0.01544544
var s1 = String(d1)      // 0.015445440000000001

var d2 = 0.01544544      // 0.01544544
var s2 = String(d2)      // 0.01544544
```

Why does converting the product of two fractional Doubles to a String result in extraneous zeroes (ending with 1) in the fractional portion of the result, but converting a fractional Double explicitly to a String does not? And how can I remove the extraneous portion from the result?

Comment: If you are looking for precision you should use Swift `Decimal` type (make sure to use the string initializer). When displaying a value to the user you should use `NumberFormatter` and specify the maximum and minimum fraction digits

Comment: Or use `String(format:)`